# How to create db table while installing a module?

Tags: database

I want to create a table in Drupal while installing a module (custom module which is crated by me). I tried in the below way, but I could not able to create a table in Drupal db. what am I missing, what else I have to do?

```
function custom_agent_handler_install() {

if (!db_table_exists('demo_score')) {
  $demo_score_schema = array(
    'description' => 'To store unique number and other details.',
    'fields' => array(
      'score'    => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),
      'timestamp' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => '0'),
    ),
  );

return $demo_score;
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implements `hook_schema()` in your `modulename.install` file. In druapl 7, you do not need to use `hook_install` to create database table.

> A Drupal schema definition is an array structure representing one or
>   more tables and their related keys and indexes. A schema is defined by
>   `hook_schema()` which must live in your `module's .install` file.

Code Snippets:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema() 
 */

function custom_travel_api_schema() {

  $schema['custom_booking'] = array(
    'description' => 'To store the booking flight.',
    'fields' => array(
      'bid' => array(
       'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'The booking id.',        
      ),
      'source' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => '255',
        'description' => 'The source city for the booking.',
      ),
      'destination' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => '255',
        'description' => 'The destination city for the booking.',
      ),
      'bdate' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,        
        'description' => 'The date of the booking',
      ),
      'amount' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,        
        'description' => 'The amount of the booking',
      ),
      'status' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,        
        'description' => 'The status of the booking(0 -> In process, 1 -> completed)',
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,        
        'description' => 'The user id of the booking',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('bid'),
  );

  return $schema;

}
```

You can check [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

BY the way, you are using $demo_score_schema and you are returning $users_score_schema.

Try this example:

```
function hook_schema() {
  $schema['node'] = array(

    // Example (partial) specification for table "node".
    'description' => 'The base table for nodes.',
    'fields' => array(
      'nid' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a node.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'vid' => array(
        'description' => 'The current {node_revision}.vid version identifier.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'type' => array(
        'description' => 'The {node_type} of this node.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 32,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'The title of this node, always treated as non-markup plain text.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'node_changed' => array('changed'),
      'node_created' => array('created'),
    ),
    'unique keys' => array(
      'nid_vid' => array('nid', 'vid'),
      'vid' => array('vid'),
    ),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'node_revision' => array(
        'table' => 'node_revision',
        'columns' => array('vid' => 'vid'),
      ),
      'node_author' => array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('nid'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes. I think I should provide the answer as the above one.